# Como hace un Where de un append o ultimo elemento de una traza en Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

necesito ayuda para hacer una subquery en Laravel 5.4 para obtener el ultimo  elemento de una relacion y filtrar donde exista para ese ultimo elemento una ID especifica

me explico

```
 class vehiculo {

   public function traza (){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comun\Traza','id_vehiculo')
   }
}

$rows = Vehiculo::whereHas('traza', function($q){
   $q->whereIn('id_estado',[406,407] );

})
->paginate();
```

pasa que al hacer eso me trae todos los vehiculos que tienen o han tenido esos estado, pero solo quiero que me devuelva los que actualmente tienen ese estado, es decir los que el ultimo elmento en su traza tienen el estado (406,407)

Comment: A qué te refieres con actualmente? Por fecha?

Comment: me vuelvo a explicar un vehiculo tiene una traza , esa trasa se guarda con estados, por ejemplo creado, pausado , etc. pero necesito filtrar los vehiculos cuya traza actual(la ultima traza que fue insertada para ese vehiculo) esten en el estado pausado o finalizado( id_estado  406, 407).

Comment: con actualmente básicamente me refiero a la ultima traza insertada.

Comment: Necesitas algún valor como fecha u hora para obtener ese registro más reciente, no veo otro modo

Comment: amigo la traza tiene tanto una fecha , como un id, por lo que se puede traer el ultimo haciendo algo como "select id_estado from traza order by id desc limit 1"  pero como hago esa subconsulta con eloquent xd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya lo resolví, de la siguiente manera

```
$rows = Vehiculo::whereHas('traza', function($q){
    $q->whereIn('traza.id_estado',[406,407])
    ->where('traza.id', function($q){
        $q->select('t.id')
        ->from('traza as t')
        ->where('traza.id_vehiculo', \DB::raw('t.id_vehiculo'))
        ->orderBy('t.created_at')
        ->limit(1);
    });
})
->paginate();
```

Comment: Imagine que tiene dos vehiculos azul y rojo y estos tiene la sigiente traza azul: [ 1 => creado , 2 => vendido ] , rojo : [ 3 =>creado  ], en la forma que ud me indica si yo busco los vehiculos que  esten en estado creado, me devolvera los dos, por que en algun punto ambos en su traza tienen "creado", mientras que en la forma que solvente solo me traera el vehiculo rojo, puesto que su ultimo estado es creado, no se si me doy a entender.

Answer (score 0):

Pues me parece que te puedes apoyar de:

- Método **`latest()`** que cumple la misma función que **`ORDER BY`** solo que este estaría tratando de ordenar por la fecha de creación, para anular ese comportamiento le pasamos como argumento la columna **`id`** para que sea por esa que haga el acomodo
- Como solo te interesa tomar 1, puedes valerte del método **`take`** e indicar como argumento la cantidad de renglones que deseas recuperar.

De tal forma que la consulta quede así:

```
$rows = Vehiculo::whereHas('traza', function($q){
   $q->whereIn('id_estado',[406,407])
     ->latest('id')
     ->take(1);
})->paginate();
```